# Does unplugged computer drain power from connected mobile phone?

Tags: usb, power, desktop-computer

When I unplugged my computer from mains it continuously drain power from connected mobile phones. I've also tried different usb ports but nothing change all ports are draining power from mobile including type-c.

Is this normal? Am I not suppose to leave my phones connected to the Pc?

I've got **ROG Strix X570-E Gaming** motherboard

Comment: What leads you to believe your phone battery is draining due to the connection with the computer? Some phones can chateh devices connected to them, some computers support communications with connected devices even when they are powered off. These are things you'll need to check your phone and computer for these features.

Comment: You wrote "but they don't search for power in the way phones.."  In my test, the phone (having been sitting on a cold desk) got slightly warm. It needs to know if attached to iTunes or is charging.  So I was not that far off the mark.

Comment: @music2myear I know because my keyboard lit up momentarily after every ~5 seconds in fact all USB devices get powered on for very short time. My both headphone's has lights on it and it also lit up same for motherboard so that's why I'm 100% sure computer is sucking power from mobile phones.

P.S; I am not talking about pc is just turned off but completely disconnected from mains socket so there is no source for those leds to get power from other than mobile phones.

Comment: You phone keyboard or your laptop keyboard? And why is that an indicator that your computer is "sucking" power from the phone? What it likely indicates is that the computer is failing to sleep properly and is not actually off at all.